# O(NLogN) shows better performance than O(N) if unordered_set is used

Tags: c++, performance, binary-search, unordered-set

```
//Time sorting O(nlogn) + binary search for N items logN = 2NLogN = 
//Time: O(NLogN). 
//space - O(1).
bool TwoSum::TwoSumSortAndBinarySearch(int* arr, int size, int sum)
{
    sort(arr, arr + size);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (binary_search(arr + i + 1, arr + size, sum - arr[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


//Time: O(N) as time complexity of Add and Search in hashset/unordered_set is O(1).
//Space: O(N)
bool TwoSum::TwoSumHashSet(int* arr, int size, int sum)
{
    unordered_set<int> hash;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (hash.find(sum - arr[i]) != hash.end())
            return true;
        hash.insert(arr[i]);
    }
    return false;
}

int* TwoSum::Testcase(int size)
{
    int* in = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {       
        in[i] = rand() % (size + 1);//random number b/w 0 to N.
    }
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 5000000;
    int* in = TwoSum::Testcase(size);
    
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();//clock start 
    bool output = TwoSum::TwoSumHashSet(in, size, INT_MAX);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();//clock end

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";   
}
```

I measured the performance of the above two methods, where I would like to find the TwoSum problem.
In the First approach, I am sorting the array then using binary search.
Time: O(NLogN).
space - O(1).

In the second approach, [unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) is used whose complexity is constant on average, worst case linear in the size of the container.

//Time: O(N) as time complexity of Add and Search in hashset/unordered_set is O(1).
//Space: O(N)

Here are the three runs time taken by these two methods

### TwoSumSortAndBinarySearch---------------TwoSumHashSet

---

1. 8.05---------------------------------------15.15

---

2. 7.76---------------------------------------14.47

---

3. 7.74---------------------------------------14.28

So, it is clear that TwoSumSortAndBinarySearch performs definitely better than unordered_Set.

Which approach is more preferable and suggested in real scenario and why?

Comment: Keep in mind that Big O notation represents the behavior of an algorithm *as the input set's size tends to infinity*. If you don't have infinite input data, constant and lower order overhead can still be significant.

Comment: Locality and branch prediction is *huge* for performance. Sorted data can be very fast to work with. Even with higher order time complexity, if those operations are much faster than your alternative algorithm it may still be faster. This ties in with my previous comment.

Comment: "Any thought on this?" is kinda vague question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: It would be interesting to know the `size` of your use case

Comment: @Damien `int size = 5000000; int* in = TwoSum::Testcase(size);`.

Comment: int size = 5000000;

Comment: you measure absolute time while complexity tells you close to zero about that. You can have a O(N) algorithm that performs worse than a O(N^500) one in absolute terms for some N

Comment: This is why arrays (and vectors) rock.  The data they store is all in one location making their cache locality great.  Using an `unordered_set` you're going have at least one cache miss for every element you access.  Using an array, unless you are jumping around randomly on a array to big to fit in the cache, you don't get the cache misses.  There is a really good talk about this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry, I read too fast. This is a rather large value. I am surprised that the *crossing point* has not been met

Comment: @Damien As I and others have mentioned, the difference is probably due to locality. Operating on cache is significantly faster than having to read from RAM. I've seen numbers like 40 and 100 CPU cycles are needed to load a chunk from RAM, but I'll admit I don't know exactly. And log2(5000000) is only about 22.

Comment: Yo do unnecessary work for `hash` sets. You first do a lookup, then you ignore the result and do the insertion. Just check the second element of the pair returned by `insert` and see how it'll work. Also, specify the compiler you've used.

Comment: @DanM. I am using MS Visual studio 2019

Comment: Keep in mind that every `unordered_set` insert is doing a memory allocation.  This adds a considerable amount of time to every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is because computational complexity doesn’t take into account the behavior of multi-level memory system present in every modern computer. And it is precisely because you measure that behavior via proxy using time (!!), that your measurement is not “like” theoretical computational complexity. **Computational complexity predicts execution times only in very well controlled situations, when the code is optimal for the platform**. If you want to measure complexity, you can’t measure time. Measure operation counts. It will agree with theory then.

In my limited experience, it is rather rare that computational complexity theory would predict runtimes on reasonably sized data sets, when the behavior is neither exponential nor cubic (or higher terms). Cache access patterns and utilization of architectural parallelism are major predictors of performance, before computational complexity comes into play.